How to disable Quick Actions / Lightbulb / Screwdriver feature for Javascript in Visual Studio 2022?
Is there a way to disable the Quick Actions / Lightbulb / Screwdriver feature for Javascript in Visual Studio 2022?
I mean this annoying icon:

I've seen this question, but it seems to be related to C# only.
According to this, there is no standard setting, but maybe an extension could do the thing?

I also have been experiencing this issue and am not sure there's a way to disable it in VSCode but just try to avoid using Ctrl + . as a keyboard shortcut because it triggers the quick actions menu often.

I don't use the shortcut. I see the icon every time, when I click within a function. VS suggests “Move to a new file”.

After my search and testing, as you mentioned in the relevant post, VS does not currently have settings to disable these functions. If you really want this feature, I suggest you report this feature request to DC. There are more VS developers on DC, and they may be able to help you:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/VisualStudio/suggest
It is important to note that if there are enough users submitting requests for this feature, Microsoft may process the feature request in this area, and if there are not many users submitting the feature request, Microsoft may not consider this aspect of the feature.
